# Trying to get the website to scroll to section when clicked in Navbar

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll library for smooth scrolling.Whenever I click the section in the Navbar I want to go to nothing happens. I have reviewed my code, but I can't seem to figure out why this error is happening.

Here is my App file. I took some of th sections out to simplify it.Right now I have just been trying to get it to scroll to the About section:

```js
import {React, useEffect, useState} from "react";

import Hero from "./Hero";
import About from "./About";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import WorkExperience from "./WorkExperience";
import Contact from "./Contact";



function App() {

  const [selectedPage, setSelectedPage] = useState("home");
  const [isTopOfPage, setIsTopOfPage] = useState(true);
  
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (window.scrollY === 0) {
        setIsTopOfPage(true);
        setSelectedPage("home");
      }
      if (window.scrollY !== 0) setIsTopOfPage(false);
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className="bg-[rgb(36,36,36)] text-white h-screen snap-y snap-mandatory overflow-         y-scroll overflow-x-hidden z-0
      scrollbar scrollbar-track-gray-400/20 scrollbar-thumb-[#0A81F7]/80"
    >
      <Navbar
       isTopOfPage={isTopOfPage}
       selectedPage={selectedPage}
       setSelectedPage={setSelectedPage}
      />
      
      
        

      <section id="home">
        <Hero/>
      </section>
      <section id="about">
       <About/>
       
      </section>
      <section id="experience">
       <WorkExperience/>
       
      </section>
  
     </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is my Navbar code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { SocialIcon } from "react-social-icons";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import AnchorLink from "react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll";
import { Menu as MenuIcon, Clear as ClearIcon } from '@mui/icons-material';
import useMediaQuery from "./hooks/useMediaQuery";

const Link = ({ page, selectedPage, setSelectedPage }) => {
  const lowerCasePage = page.toLowerCase();
  return (
    <AnchorLink
      style={{
        padding: "0.5rem 1rem",
        border: "1px solid #242424",
        borderRadius: "9999px",
        textTransform: "uppercase",
        fontSize: "0.75rem",
        letterSpacing: "0.125rem",
        color: selectedPage === lowerCasePage ? "#0A81F7" : "#FF8C00",
        transition: "all 0.3s",
        ":hover": {
          borderColor: "#FF8C00",
          color: "#0A81F7",
        },
      }}
      href={`#${lowerCasePage}`}
      
      onClick={() => setSelectedPage(lowerCasePage)}
    >
      {page}
    </AnchorLink>
  );
};

const Navbar = ({  selectedPage, setSelectedPage }) => {
  const [isMenuToggled, setIsMenuToggled] = useState(false);
  const isDesktop = useMediaQuery("(min-width: 768px)");
  

 

  return (
    <nav className="sticky top-0 p-5 flex items-start justify-between max-w-8xl mx-auto z-20 xl:items-center">
        
      <motion.div
        initial={{
          x: -500,
          opacity: 0,
          scale: 0.5,
        }}
        animate={{
          x: 0,
          opacity: 1,
          scale: 1,
        }}
        transition={{
          duration: 1.5,
        }}
        className="flex flex-row items-center"
      >
        <SocialIcon
          url="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jeremy-carpenter-1119b393/"
          fgColor="gray"
          bgColor="transparent"
        />
        <SocialIcon
          url="https://github.com/buckoon"
          fgColor="gray"
          bgColor="transparent"
        />
      </motion.div>

      {isDesktop ? (
        <motion.div
          initial={{
            x: 500,
            opacity: 0,
            scale: 0.5,
          }}
          animate={{
            x: 0,
            opacity: 1,
            scale: 1,
          }}
          transition={{ duration: 1.5 }}
          className="flex flex-row items-center text-gray-300 cursor-pointer"
        >
            <div className="pt-7 ml-5">
                <Link
                    page="Home"
                    selectedPage={selectedPage}
                    setSelectedPage={setSelectedPage}
                />
                <Link
                    page="About"
                    selectedPage={selectedPage}
                    setSelectedPage={setSelectedPage}
                />
                <Link
                    page="Experience"
                    selectedPage={selectedPage}
                    setSelectedPage={setSelectedPage}
                />
                <Link
                    page="Skills"
                    selectedPage={selectedPage}
                    setSelectedPage={setSelectedPage}
                />
                <Link
                    page="Projects"
                    selectedPage={selectedPage}
                    setSelectedPage={setSelectedPage}
                />
                <Link
                    page="Contact"
                    selectedPage={selectedPage}
                    setSelectedPage={setSelectedPage}
                />
           </div>
        </motion.div>
      ) : (
        <button
          className="rounded-full bg-red p-2"
          onClick={() => setIsMenuToggled(!isMenuToggled)}
        >
          <MenuIcon />
        </button>
      )}


        {!isDesktop && isMenuToggled && (
          <div className="fixed right-0 bottom-0 h-full bg-blue w-[300px]">
            {/* CLOSE ICON */}
                <div className="flex justify-end p-12">
                <button onClick={() => setIsMenuToggled(!isMenuToggled)}>
                    <ClearIcon/>
                </button>
                </div>

                
                <div className="flex flex-col gap-10 ml-[33%] text-2xl text-deep-blue">
                    <Link
                        page="Home"
                        selectedPage={selectedPage}
                        setSelectedPage={setSelectedPage}
                    />
                    <Link
                        page="About"
                        selectedPage={selectedPage}
                        setSelectedPage={setSelectedPage}
                    />
                    <Link
                        page="Experience"
                        selectedPage={selectedPage}
                        setSelectedPage={setSelectedPage}
                    />
                    <Link
                        page="Skills"
                        selectedPage={selectedPage}
                        setSelectedPage={setSelectedPage}
                    />
                    <Link
                        page="Projects"
                        selectedPage={selectedPage}
                        setSelectedPage={setSelectedPage}
                    />
                    <Link
                        page="Contact"
                        selectedPage={selectedPage}
                        setSelectedPage={setSelectedPage}
                    />
                </div>
          </div>
        )}      



    </nav>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: use #sectionID in href of <Link/>

Comment: If you look at the top of the Navbar component I am already using the href.

Comment: can yo;u reproduce this in codesandbox?